# How can I pull various claims out of the access token?

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm using the [msal.js library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) to connect to Azure AD B2C for a reactjs client application.

I can login and get the access token. I can dump that token into [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) and see the claims that I've specified in my sign in policy. But I'm missing how I can pull the claim data out within the application.

Does the msal library have a method to extend the user to include those claims?
 Looking at the examples to get the user's name I'm thinking something like...
`clientApplication.getUser().myCustomClaim`

Alternatively does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to pull that claim data out of the token?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Referenced the "dev" commit.

In [the "dev" branch](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev), [this commit](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/commit/eeaf91927b00f6d234cdf5b5de647bcc3e432b40) adds the **idToken** property to the **User** object.

You can reference the identity token claims as follows:

```
clientApplication.getUser().idToken["mycustomclaim"]
```

Comment: I'm using v0.1.3 and don't see the idToken property. Just displayableId, name, identityProvider, and userIdentifier.

Comment: Apologies, I was referring to the "dev" branch which hasn't been merged as yet, not the "master" branch (the v0.1.3 release).

Comment: And the beta is now deployed to NPM :)  [Reference](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/251#issuecomment-367470568) @mark